# Can I use a custom data format when using Vue + Chartjs

Tags: vue.js, chart.js

Everywhere I look the format of the data for a chartjs component must be on the form

```
[
  {x: x1, y: y1},
  {x: x2, y: y2},
  .
  .
  {x: xn, y: yn},
]
```

when plotting f.x a line chart

```
<chartjs-line
  :data="item"
/>
```

However, my data is in another format

```
[
  {date: date_1, value: value_1},
  {date: date_2, value: value_2},
  .
  .
  {date: date_n, value: value_2},
]
```

Is there a way to pass this format over to the component so I wont need to reformat the data?

Comment: Is not possible to use Point[ ]?,  https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html, i was reading about change X/Y axis dictionary and only found how to change labels. Other option is make a method or computed property to transform.

Comment: Yeah ... I suspect you are going to transform the data after all

Answer (score 1):

x and y are points in space, dataset not allow change of name.

Nearest option comes here: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html#updating-options

But why go so far if you can do your problem fixed with a computed property:

```
computed:{
   transformData(){
      return this.data.map(el=> { return {x:el.date, y:el.date} })
   }
}
```